# php tcpdf image string filter

Tags: php, tcpdf

I've been trying to email a table containing a list of fieldname-value. When I reach an image value, I filter out the image string for use in tcpdf image output. I did a conditional that if data:image/png is found, it should be removed. Otherwise, remove data:image/jpeg.

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(50, 0, '', '', "{$fieldname}", 1, 0, 0, true, 'R', true);   

$base64 = strpos("data:image/png", $col_value) ? str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", $field_value) : str_replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "", $field_value);

$imgdata = base64_decode($base64);

$pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata, '', '', 0,65, '', '', 'B', false, 300, 'R');

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 10, '', '', "", 1, 1, 0, true, '', true);
```

which results:

> TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image: @

without the conditional / doing an if/else for the $base64 value, I dont get the error. But my base64 wont be as flexible as with two types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it! explode() worked... Then instead of pdf->Image, I just put a temp. image for img tag's src attribute.

- get the string with [getimagefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php)
- save a temp image from string
- then use img tag in $pdf->writeHTMLCell

  ```
  $base64 = explode(',', $col_value);
  $base64d = base64_decode($base64[1]);

  $im = imagecreatefromstring($base64d);
                      if ($im !== false) {
                          echo 'image ok';
                          //header('Content-Type: image/png');
                          imagejpeg($im, $path . "test.jpg");
                          imagedestroy($im);
                          echo "<br /> image done";
                      }
                      else {
                          echo 'An error occurred.';
                      }
  $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 30, '', '', '<img src="' .$path . 'test.jpg"/>', 1, 1, 0, true, 'C', true);
  unlink($path . "test.jpg");
  ```